# Pyaudio/Portaudio issue in synchronizing read/write buffers

Tags: latency, pyaudio, portaudio

My sampler (sound blaster) is 96000hz.
I need to syncronize the output signal with the input signal, so the time_info is critical for us. We need to know the exact time difference between the first sample of of the output buffer and the first sample of the input buffer.

However, the problem is that the time_info gap between two consecutive write or read buffers (callbacks) are not the same. For example:
My buffer is 19200 for the read and write and when I print it each callback I get:

```
Time gap between READ  buffers: 0.19993333332968177274 
Time gap between WRITE buffers: 0.20000299999810522422

Time gap between READ  buffers: 0.20001300000149058178 
Time gap between WRITE buffers: 0.20000299999810522422

Time gap between READ  buffers: 0.20000900000013643876 
Time gap between WRITE buffers: 0.20000099999742815271

Time gap between READ  buffers: 0.19996774999162880704 
Time gap between WRITE buffers: 0.19999800000368850306
```

19200 / 96000 should be 0.2 seconds always, but I get different times in the time_info, which eliminates my ability to sync the output with the input.
I am working with a 40khz sound wave, so in order to sync the phase I need the times to be accurate by 1 microsecond maximum.

Is this a problem in PortAudio? Is this a problem in my sound card? Do these time_info numbers come from the sound card (the hardware) or from PortAudio?

I am using PyAudio (PortAudio binding for Python) in Ubuntu.

Comment: I can reproduce high fluctuations on Linux/ALSA using the default device. However, when using device `hw:0,0` (a cheap built-in soundcard) the values vary only around 100 microseconds (still much more than your values). Using Linux/JACK, the variation is a bit more than 100 microseconds. This for sure strongly depends on the hardware. I *think* this is not caused by the Python layer but by PortAudio itself. You should ask on the [mailing list](http://portaudio.com/contacts.html).